# How to check if value starts with and ends with either of 2 options using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this current `if` statement - which is inside a `for loop`:

```
// Validate Temperatures
if(inputs[i].name.startsWith("actual-temp") || inputs[i].name.startsWith("min-temp") || inputs[i].name.startsWith("max-temp")) {
    validate(parseFloat(inputs[i].value), inputs[i], e);
}
```

**What it does**

Checks all inputs that has name starting with `actual-temp`, `min-temp` and `max-temp` and passes them into a function called `validate`

**My HTML file**

```html
<input type="number" name="max-temp-1">
<input type="number" name="max-temp-1">
<input type="number" name="max-temp-1">

<input type="number" name="min-temp-1">
<input type="number" name="min-temp-1">
<input type="number" name="min-temp-1">

<input type="number" name="actual-temp-1">
<input type="number" name="actual-temp-1">
<input type="number" name="actual-temp-1">



<input type="number" name="max-temp-2">
<input type="number" name="max-temp-2">
<input type="number" name="max-temp-2">

<input type="number" name="min-temp-2">
<input type="number" name="min-temp-2">
<input type="number" name="min-temp-1">

<input type="number" name="actual-temp-2">
<input type="number" name="actual-temp-2">
<input type="number" name="actual-temp-2">



<input type="number" name="max-temp-3">
<input type="number" name="max-temp-3">
<input type="number" name="max-temp-3">

<input type="number" name="min-temp-3">
<input type="number" name="min-temp-3">
<input type="number" name="min-temp-3">

<input type="number" name="actual-temp-3">
<input type="number" name="actual-temp-3">
<input type="number" name="actual-temp-3">
```

**Question**

Within my if statement - how can I grab all elements that `startsWith()` (as it is in the `if` statement currently) and ends with either `-1` or `-2`? Or alternatively exclude inputs names that end with `-3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for your test

```
if (inputs[i].name.match(/^(actual|min|max)-temp-(1|2)$/)) {
    validate(parseFloat(inputs[i].value), inputs[i], e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [str.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```
    if(inputs[i].name.includes("actual-temp") || inputs[i].name.includes("min-temp") || inputs[i].name.includes("max-temp")) {
        validate(parseFloat(inputs[i].value), inputs[i], e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let item of my_list) {

    if (item.charAt(item.length-1)!=="3"&&
        (item.startsWith("actual-temp")|| item.startsWith("min-temp")|| 
         item.startsWith("max-temp"))
        ) {

    //logic goes here
    }
}
```

when the first condition in the above if loop fails , javascript will not check  the 3 items in OR statements (short circuiting comes into picture)